# Regular Expressions: how can I find words of any length alphabetically after a certain word

Tags: regex

If given a certain word like PLEASE, what Regex can I write that would match with any word that would come, alphabetically, in a dictionary after that word.

For example, given PLEASE: APPLE would not be matched, but POST would match, POW would match, MEAGER would match, etc. Anything that comes after it alphabetically.

I'm struggling especially because the length can change to be longer or shorter.
RegEx are required, I can't use any other search tool.

Comment: What have you tried? This will be difficult without some sort of code...

Comment: Sorry about that, new to posting on stackoverflow. User horcrux answered my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
^(?:[Q-Z]|P[M-Z]|PL[F-Z]|PLE[B-Z]|PLEA[T-Z]|PLEAS[F-Z]|PLEASE\w)\w*$
```

This regex matches a word *starting* with:

- a letter from `Q` to `Z` or
- `P` followed by a letter from `M` to `Z` or
- `PL` followed by a letter from `F` to `Z` or
- `PLE` followed by a letter from `B` to `Z` or
- `PLEA` followed by a letter from `T` to `Z` or
- `PLEAS` followed by a letter from `F` to `Z` or
- `PLEASE` followed by any another letter

Notice: this will work only with latin alphabet without diacritics.

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/B7g9rZ/1)